# Plotting a long and complex airy function

Tags: plotting, special-functions, complex

I try to plot an Airy function

```
y[x_] := -(((-1)^(
   5/6) (AiryAi[-(-1)^(2/3) (-2 + I x)] AiryBi[2 (-1)^(2/3)] - 
     AiryAi[2 (-1)^(2/3)] AiryBi[-(-1)^(2/3) (-2 + I x)]))/(
  AiryAiPrime[2 (-1)^(2/3)] AiryBi[2 (-1)^(2/3)] - 
   AiryAi[2 (-1)^(2/3)] AiryBiPrime[2 (-1)^(2/3)]))
```

using the command

```
Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[Out[2]]],{x,80,100} ]
```

Here we can see the peaks reaching beyond the "roof", is there any way to minimize it to see the tops of the waves?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't test the output in the figure without typing it. And it's not the output of `DSolve`. Can you also post the code for `Out[2]`?

Comment: For instance, I don't get a blank plot if I use the expression for `y[x]` returned by `DSolve`.  You perhaps did something to get `Out[2]` that is causing the problem, or `Out[2]` is not what you think it is. There seems to be an extra `}`, so maybe what you show for `Out[2]` is incomplete.

Comment: Added to it , thanks

Comment: With the edit, `Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[y[x]]], {x, -100, 100}]` gives me https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymOPc.png. You might be more interested in a smaller range like `{x, -5, 5}`. -- Have you seen the alternative for plotting complex-values functions of a real variable, `ReImPlot[y[x], {x, -5, 5}]`?

Comment: You are right, thanks

Comment: Try: `sol = DSolve[{y''[x] - (I x - 2) y[x] == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 1}, 
  y[x], x]` and `Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[y[x] /. First@sol]], {x, -5, 5}]`

Comment: Relative to the scale, which is on the order of `10^102`, a value like `10^99` appears to lie on the x-axis, just like a zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqns = {y''[x] - (I x - 2) y[x] == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 1};

sol = DSolve[eqns, y, x]

{{y -> Function[{x}, -(((-1)^(
         5/
          6) (AiryAi[-(-1)^(2/3) (-2 + I x)] AiryBi[2 (-1)^(2/3)] - 
           AiryAi[2 (-1)^(2/3)] AiryBi[-(-1)^(2/3) (-2 + I x)]))/(AiryAiPrime[
           2 (-1)^(2/3)] AiryBi[2 (-1)^(2/3)] - 
         AiryAi[2 (-1)^(2/3)] AiryBiPrime[2 (-1)^(2/3)]))]}}
```

Verifying the solution,

```
eqns /. sol[[1]] // Simplify

(* {True, True, True} *)

LogPlot[Evaluate[ReIm[y[x] /. sol[[1]]]], {x, -100, 100},
 WorkingPrecision -> 50,
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]

```
LogPlot[Evaluate[ReIm[y[x] /. sol[[1]]]], {x, -10, 10},
 WorkingPrecision -> 50,
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 PlotLegends -> {Re, Im}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[y[x] /. sol[[1]]]], {x, -5, 5},
 WorkingPrecision -> 50,
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 PlotLegends -> {Re, Im}]
```

[image]